# Using * in string compare?

Tags: c, string, if-statement, command, compare

I am having trouble when using a "*" when comparing strings in my C program. Is there some rule that prohibits using it? Here is the troublesome piece of code:

```cpp
else if(strcmp(argv[i], "*") == 0)
{
    printf("pos MULT: %d", pos);
    result = dubStack[pos-1] * dubStack[pos - 2];
    pos += 1;
}
```

When running the program with the code above my print statement does not run and the result is not calculated.
However if I change the character in the string compare (such as shown below; changed * to an m), the correct operation is performed and the print statement works. Is there something I'm missing when using the * for this?

```cpp
else if(strcmp(argv[i], "m") == 0)
{
    printf("pos MULT: %d", pos);
    result = dubStack[pos-1] * dubStack[pos - 2];
    pos += 1;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the symbol '*' has a special meaning in the used shell.

Comment: check the value of `argv[i]` with a debuger (or print it), as Vlad has said your shell may have replace it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to pass '#' character as a command-line argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58837835/unable-to-pass-character-as-a-command-line-argument) (different character, same problem with the shell)

Comment: Yep, your program is fine; your shell is screwing you. How to fix it? You can't. That's a fundamental design decision of Unix that was made a long time ago, wrongly IMHO, and can't be changed.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about `*` in C strings: `"*"` is an innocuous character string of length 1.

Conversely `*` is expanded by the command shell to the sorted list of names of the files and directories in the current directory. To prevent this, you must quote this character on the command line. Here are different ways to do this:

```
$ myprog 1 1 \*
$ myprog 1 1 '*'
$ myprog 1 1 "*"
```